# scope with anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#submit").click(function(event) {
  var jsonResponse = ....
  var val = jsonResponse.results[0].myId;

  externalFunc(val);
});
```

this is all in a js file in `DOCUMENTROOT/tabs/sp/js/sp.js`, while the `externalFunc` function is found in `DOCUMENTROOT/tabs/ru/js/ru.js`. I put an alert in `externalFunc` that isn't popping up, and chrome dev tools doesn't recognize `externalFunc`, so it is a scope issue.  How do I access this function only after the click event though?

Comment: Can you show how is `externalFunc` declared in `ru.js`.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

Did you include DOCUMENTROOT/tabs/ru/js/ru.js file in your html document. if not please add it. this should solve your problem.

Comment: I added "tabs/ru/js/ru.js", a path relative to the document root(where my index.html file is); just like I did for the js file holding the function that returns a value for jsonResponse.  The browser found that function(in tabs/sp/js/sp.js), but not this one.

Comment: @HukeLau_DABA are you including ru.js BEFORE sp.js?

Answer (score 0):

What seems to me is the reference issues, i mean your function file is been declared below the file which has the click event, you can try something like this:

```
<script src='ru.js'></script> //<----the function file
<script src='sp.js'></script> //<----the click event file
```